# Is plotRGB using the overview included in a geotiff to plot?

Tags: r, image, plot, raster, gdal

I have a lot of 8000 by 8000 4 layers geotiff rasters (red, green, blue, nir) and would like to fasten the display in R with plotRGB (it's very slow). I've tried to speed up the display by building overview with gdal:

```
gdaladdo -r average myfile.tif 2 4 8 16
```

but I have no speeding up of the drawing. 
Is plotRgb using the embeded overview to draw?
Is there a drawing function supporting the overviews included in the geotiff and thus speeding up the drawing?

Comment: Boy, I would seriously seriously doubt that `plotRGB` uses the embedded overview. I also see no indication at all from the `?plotRGB` help file (or the function's argument list) that it does anything of the sort.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien : Do you know another plotting RGB r function that can take advantage of the overviews embeded in the geotiff?

Comment: No, I don't, but if you ask on the [r-sig-geo mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-geo) you'll likely get a +/- authoritative answer. I'll be interested to learn the answer myself.